# Add name of active sheet to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, rename

I want the name of the active sheet added to the new worksheet.

```
Sub Add_Rename()
' Add en Rename ActiveSheet

    Dim Maand As String
    Dim test As Worksheet
    Maand = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
    Set test = ActiveSheet
    test.Name = "Digital Dossier " & Maand ' last part will not work.

End Sub
```

Comment: it works for me. what does "not work" mean?

Comment: Your code works fine. It is adding a new sheet with name as Digital Dossier and active sheet name.

Comment: "*will not work*" is not helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Max character length of a sheet name is 31. Make sure the original sheet name plus the sheet name you are appending to the original  name is not greater than the maximum.

See this article for for more info on sheet naming, etc.  http://www.excelcodex.com/2012/06/worksheets-naming-conventions/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added the sheetnames.